# Calculate font size of the app dynamically in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have these three factors :

> ScreenWidth
>
> ScreenHeight
>
> ScaleFactor

or device sizes in Android,IOS,And UWP.

I want to calculate the font size of the app dynamically.

Is there Any formula for calculating the font size in a double value from these factors ?

Or Micro,Small,Medium,Large Xamarin font sizes ?

Comment: Are you referring to the sizes of the `NamedSize` enumeration? If so, [this is the conversion for Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6d5186c8acbf37b877c7ca3c77a378352a3743d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/FontExtensions.cs#L21) and [this is the conversion for iOS](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6d5186c8acbf37b877c7ca3c77a378352a3743d/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/FontExtensions.cs#L20) in Xamarin Forms. UWP and other platform also have the same Font extensions.

Comment: Each OS has a default/standard typography and it is not based upon device size, but based upon legibility and accessibility settings. Refer to the iOS `Dynamic Type Sizes` chart and you can scroll between the accessibility styles and see various point sizes for each style @ https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/ (Google and MS also have charts)  If you really want to resize fonts based upon device metrics (called `grandma` mode by designers), I recommend reading the "multiplier" section @ http://sebastien-gabriel.com/designers-guide-to-dpi/